# Transformation Theorem and Showing Independence of N(0,1) Random Variables

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

I am trying to solve the following problem:

> Show that the following procedure generates $N(0, 1)$-distributed random
>   numbers: Pick two independent $U(0, 1)$-distributed numbers $U_1$ and $U_2$
>   and set $X = \sqrt{−2 \log U_1 }·\cos(2 \pi U_2)$ and $Y = \sqrt{−2 \log U_1} ·\sin(2 \pi U_2)$. Show that $X$ and $Y$ are independent $N(0, 1)$-distributed random variables.

I am trying to apply the transformation theorem for multivariate random variables.  So far I have:
$f_{X,Y}(x,y)=f_{U_1,U_2}(u_1(x,y),u_2(x,y))|J|$

where $u_1(x,y),u_2(x,y)$ are the expressions for $u_1,u_2$ in terms of $x,y$.  Then I could apply the independence of $U_1,U_2$ to split the joint distribution into the two $U(0,1)$ distributions and substitute in the expressions for $u_1(x,y),u_2(x,y)$.

I just feel like something is off because trying to solve $X = \sqrt{−2 \log U_1 }·\cos(2 \pi U_2)$ and $Y = \sqrt{−2 \log U_1} ·\sin(2 \pi U_2)$ for $U_1,U_2$ and then solving for the Jacobian seems excessively difficult.

Any tips or ideas would be very helpful.  Thanks.

Update:
You can solve it using what is outlined above.  The algebraic details are filled in here as well in section 2.4.3:
http://www.mathematik.uni-ulm.de/numerik/teaching/ss09/NumFin/Script/chap2_4-2_5.pdf

Comment: Nevertheless this is more or less what is to be done... As a preliminary, separate, step, you might want to compute the distribution of $R=\sqrt{-2\log U_1}$.

Comment: I think I've posted an answer to this question here before. ${}\qquad{}$